# Can libraries built across multiple Android ndk versions work together?

Tags: android-ndk

I am working on an Android C++ project that requires me to build a new shared library and make a call into this library from existing code. Existing code uses a version of ndk that is quite old. I am thinking of using the latest version of ndk to build my shared library. My thought is, as long as the API and the ABI match, the integration should work fine.

Wondering if you see any issues with this approach.

Both, existing code and the new code, use stl. I am thinking I will simply link my code with static stl libraries to avoid any runtime conflicts. Do you think this would work? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I observed only an issue when diferent native parts (prebuilts libraries and project libraries) were used different STL linkage. Prebuilts libraries were compiled by using `static STL library` but the project libraries used `shared STL library` and therefore sometimes code worked strangely (in my case it was an issue with using `std::fstream` and `std::locale::facet` due to global variables of template classes were instatiated twice).

Answer (score 1):

They usually do but it's a wholly untested configuration, and ABI breakages do happen.

If it's an option you should always match your NDK versions.