# Ubuntu+CMake, Cannot static-build C/C++ android-ndk programs

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

my friend, I've come across the following problem that gives me a headache. Can you help me to point out where the problem is?

### NDK r20b

Building the environment involves three libraries

1. C ++ 11/ STL
2. OpenSSL 1.1.1i
3. Boost 1.7.0

The above three libraries, through the static library link to the target-exe

A：
`-DANDROID_STL=c++_static` is specified on the `cmake` command line, but make compiled `android-cxx-program` still requires dynamic loading `libc++_shared.so` file！

B：
I tried to compile statically by replacing a / so and other files in the directory of NDK tool chain, but encountered either the symbol “C++/STL” could not be found, or it had no effect.

I forced cmake link `libc++_static.a` file, except after the built file volume increases, but for dependence still needed `libc++_shared.so`!

Now I don't know how to compile without relying on `libc++_shared.so`.

### Supplement:

Because, it needs to be compiled into an independent exe executable Android C/C++ native program, which is not called through Java / JNI, and now it can not solve the problem of not relying on `libc++_shared.so`.

Comment: How did you build ```android-cxx-program```? Via AndroidStudio gradle?

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk It's not gradle, it's built through the NDK cmake tool-chains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [NDK C++ library support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support):

> In general, you can only use a static variant of the C++ runtime if you have one and only one shared library in your application.

> Note: This rule applies to both your code and your third party dependencies.

So, it means that you need to compile all of your stuff with `"-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"`.

Also here is an example of what can happen when using different STL libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66050613/5130269

Comment: Thank you. According to the literature you just provided, it is very helpful to me. I have solved this problem!

Now after the build, I don't need to rely on "libc++_shared.so". The problem is that I don't read the ndk document carefully enough. Sorry for the trouble, my friends!

In fact, you only need to specify "-static libstdc++" for linker (LD) in cmake, and the default is "-libstdc++".

SET(CMAKE_ EXE_ LINKER_ FLAGS "-static-libstdc++ -rdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic")

Because I didn't look up the document more carefully, which caused trouble to everyone. I'm sorry to say that here!